# Can XenApp published browser pass clientname in HTTP Request?

Tags: citrix, xenapp

In trying to lock down access to a web application too only users within a XenApp environment.  Is it possible to send the clientname in the HTTP payload by customizing something in the XenApp server (registry, etc)? These users will be using Internet Explorer in the xenapp session.

Similar in theory to how a proxy server passes a X-Forwarded-For header.

We know WHO the end-user, since the have authenticated, but we also need to identify the end-user device distinctly from other users.

Comment: I think you'll have a much easier time using IP address restrictions. Spoofing the IP address isn't as easy as it is manipulating a HTTP header

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution, as we currently are not able to detect the client at the proxy server - we only see the citrix server used.